# rectilinear motion and the derivative as a rate of change

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If A(x) square centimeters is the area of a square having a side of x centimeters, use a calculator to compute the average rate of change of A(x) with respect to x as x changes from (a) 4.000 to 4.600; (b) 4.000 to 4.300; (c) 4.000 to 4.100; (d) 4.000 to 4.050. (e) What is the instantaneous rate of change of A(x) with respect to x when x is 4?

Answer (score 0):

A(x) = x^2, defined by the question.\
a) A(4) = 16, A(4.6) = 21.16
   Average rate of change is (A(4.600)-A(4.000))/(4.600-4.000) = 8.6\
b) A(4.300) = 18.49
   Average rate of change is (A(4.300)-A(4.000))/(4.300-4.000) = 8.3\
c) A(4.100) = 16.81
   Average rate of change is (A(4.100)-A(4.000))/(4.100-4.000) = 8.1\
d) A(4.050) = 16.4025
   Average rate of change is (A(4.050)-A(4.000))/(4.050-4.000) = 8.05\
This is a question that is introducing the concept of a limit. If the preceding results are considered it should be clear that as 4+\delta gets smaller, the average rate of change is getting closer to 8. \When \delta is zero this is the limiting point which gives the instantaneous rate of change, in this case, 8.